# Trying to bind current value in *ngFor to global variable

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

As per title, I'm trying to bind the current value in the loop to a component variable so I can then pass it into another function when a button outside the loop ui is pressed. (Basically I have a menu outside the loop which can perform functions.)

I've tried a few different ways, the latest being (change) to set the variable, but it doesn't seem to work.

View component code

```
<ion-slides pager="false">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let year of years | async; let i = index; let first = first; let last = last;" value="year" (change)="currentYear = years[i]">
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-icon *ngIf="!first" name="arrow-back" (tap)="slidePrev(i)"></ion-icon>

                Year {{ year.year }}

            <ion-icon *ngIf="!last" name="arrow-forward" (tap)="slideNext(i)"></ion-icon>
        </ion-col>
     </ion-row>
     <ion-row>
         <ion-col>
             <div *ngIf="year.semesters.length === 0">
                 <p>Looks like you haven't added a semester yet</p>
                 <button (tap)="addSemester(year)">
                   <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
                 </button>
             </div>
             <div *ngIf="year.semesters.length > 0">

             <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="selectedSemester">
                 <ion-segment-button *ngFor="let sem of year.semesters" value="{{ sem.yearId + '_' + sem.semester }}">
                     Semester {{ sem.semester }}
                 </ion-segment-button>
                 <ion-segment-button (click)="addSemester(year)" *ngIf="year.semesters.length < 4">
                     Add Semester
                 </ion-segment-button>
             </ion-segment>

                </div>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Component code

```
currentYear: any;

this.years = this.gradesProvider.getYears(this.userId).snapshotChanges()
      .map(years => {
        return years.map(year => {
          const data = year.payload.doc.data();
          const id = year.payload.doc.id;
          return this.gradesProvider.getSemesters(id).valueChanges()
            .map(semesters => Object.assign({}, {id, ...data, semesters}));

        });
      }).mergeMap(observables => combineLatest(observables))
```

Other functions

```
slideNext() {
    this.slides.lockSwipes(false);
    this.selectedSemester = null;
    this.slides.slideNext();
    this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
  }

  slidePrev() {
    this.slides.lockSwipes(false);
    this.selectedSemester = null;
    this.slides.slidePrev();
    this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
  }
```

Comment: I don't understand. Please show which button, which variables are the issue, and where is this outside menu?

Comment: I just want to bind the current year in the loop to another variable, called currentYear so I can then pass this to another function

Comment: @cgTag I just can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: When the user clicks the button you need to know what the value of "year" is for that button?

Comment: @cgTag No when the page loads I need the current year object to be assigned to currentYear. Then when I click the button it will just use the pre assigned variable.

Comment: @CgTag And also when the year changes, it should update the currentYear. Kind of tracking the current loop object and assigning it to a variable for use outside the loop itself.

Comment: The variable `years` is an observable that emits an array of `year` objects. Is the `currentYear` variable suppose to equal one of those `year` objects?

Comment: @cgTag that is what I'm trying to do

Comment: okay, and which one of the `year` objects should `currentYear` be set too when the page first loads?

Comment: position 0 in the array is the default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the initialize value of `currentYear` using a `do()` operator on the observable.

```
currentYear: any;

this.years = this.gradesProvider.getYears(this.userId).snapshotChanges()
  .map(years => {
    return years.map(year => {
      const data = year.payload.doc.data();
      const id = year.payload.doc.id;
      return this.gradesProvider.getSemesters(id).valueChanges()
        .map(semesters => Object.assign({}, {id, ...data, semesters}));

    });
  })
  .mergeMap(observables => combineLatest(observables))
  .do((years)=> {
      if(!this.currentYear) {
         this.currentYear = years[0];
      }
  });
```

This will assign the first element to `currentYear` only once. After that you can change the value of `currentYear` when the user clicks the button.

You might want to use `<div *ngIf="currentYear">` in your template where code depends the variable `currentYear` to have a value, because it might not have a value right away.

Comment: Awesome Ill give that a try. I use these to change to the next item in the loop, so I can just assign it based on the index? so I add let i = index on the loop in the view, and then passed this into the function? Added functions to main answer

Comment: Yes, but if you're going to do that. You might as well just `subscribe` and assign `years` to a variable instead of using `years | async` in the template. I actually don't use `async` very often because you have need the array values elsewhere which is what happen with your example.

Comment: Hmm I've had a good trying to convert my code to a straight subscription but keep getting errors..